# jqGrid getGridParam('colModel') missing information

Tags: jqgrid

I would like capture the colModel for my jqGrid when the page unloads and store it in session so the next time the user comes to the page it can be loaded automatically.  But, the information returned by ('#contract_grid').getGridParam('colModel') is missing part or all of the information in searchoptions for the grid columns.

Any idea why this is or how to capture the full colModel?  The grid works great on the initial load but without the other searchoptions params, the filter bar features/menus don't work when I refresh the page from the colModel stored in session.

Create the default colModel for the grid

```
var defaultColModel = 
[

    {name:'REQUESTID'
        ,index:'requestID'
        ,label:'Request ID'
        ,search:true
        ,stype:'text'
        ,width:75
        ,key:true
        ,hidden:false
    },  
    {name:'REQUESTEDDATE'
        ,index:'requestedDate'
        ,label:'Request Date'
        ,sorttype:"date"
        ,search:true
        ,width:50
        ,searchoptions:{
            dataInit:function(el){jQuery(el).daterangepicker(
                            {
                            arrows:false
                            , dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
                            , onClose: function(dateText, inst){ jQuery("#contract_grid")[0].triggerToolbar();}
                            , onOpen: function() {
                                jQuery('div.ui-daterangepickercontain').css({"top": jQuery('#mouseY').val() + 'px', "left": jQuery('#mouseX').val() + 'px' });
                            }

                        });
                }
            }
        ,hidden:false
    },

    {name:'BUSINESSOWNERPERSONID'
        ,index:'businessOwnerPersonID'
        ,label:'Business Owner'
        ,search:true
        ,stype:'select'
        ,width:100
        ,hidden:false
        ,searchoptions: {
             dataUrl: 'cfc/com_common.cfc?method=getAjxPeople&role=businessOwnerPersonID',
             buildSelect: function(resp) {
                 var sel= '<select><option value=""></option><option value="7583,1636">My Reports</option>';
                 var obj = $.parseJSON(resp);
                 $.each(obj, function() {
                     sel += '<option value="'+this['lk_value']+ '">'+this['lk_option'] + "</option>"; // label and value are returned from Java layer
                 });
                 sel += '</select>';
                 return sel;
             },          
             dataEvents: [{  
                 type: 'change',
                 fn: function(e) {
                     alert(this.value)
                 }
             }]
         }
    }
];
```

When user navigates away from page, save the grid to session so it loads when they come back

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
     takeSnapshot();     
});
function takeSnapshot(){
var gridInfo = new Object();
    gridInfo.colModel = jQuery('#contract_grid').getGridParam('colModel');
    gridInfo.postData = jQuery('#contract_grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
    var snapshotData = JSON.stringify(gridInfo);

 $.ajax({
    url:  "actions/act_filter.cfc?method=takeSnapshot",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: {gridName:'contract_grid'
            ,gridParamName:'contractGridParams'
            ,filterData:snapshotData

    }
});
```

}

Create grid variable

```
var myGrid = jQuery("#contract_grid").jqGrid({
    url:            'cfc/com_ajxRequestNew.cfc?method=getReqJSON&returnformat=json',
    datatype:       'json',
    postData:       {filters: myFilters},
    mtype:          'POST',
    search:         true,
    colModel:       defaultColModel,
    altRows:        true,
    emptyrecords:   'NO CONTRACTS FOUND',
    height:         400,
    width:          1200,
    sortname:       lastSortName,
    sortorder:      lastSortOrder,
    page:           lastPage,
    pager:          jQuery('#report_pager'),
    rowNum:         lastRowNum,
    rowList:        [10,20,50,100],
    viewrecords:    true,
    clearSearch:    false,
    caption:        "Contracts Dashboard",
    sortable:       true,
    shrinkToFit:    false,
    ajaxSelectOptions: {type: "GET"},
    gridComplete: function() {
        //set the selected toolbar filter values
        var myFields = JSON.parse(myFilters);
        //set fields in form at top. filter contains index value so get corresponding name value because its used in the column label #gs
        if ( myFields['rules'].length > 0 ) {
            for (var i=0; i < myFields['rules'].length; i++ ) {
                $.each(defaultColModel, function(j) {
                    if(this.index == myFields['rules'][i]['field'] ) {
                        thisFieldName = this.name;
                        jQuery('#gs_' + thisFieldName).val( myFields['rules'][i]['data'] ); 
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
});
jQuery("#contract_grid").navGrid('#report_pager',{
    edit:false,
    add:false,
    del:false,
    search:false,
    refresh:false
}).navButtonAdd("#report_pager",{ caption:"Clear",title:"Clear Filters", buttonicon :'ui-icon-trash',
    onClickButton: function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "/assets/js/ajx_clearFilter.cfm?showHeader=0",
          async: false,
          type: "POST",
          data: ({variableName:'session.contractGridParams'})
        });
        myGrid[0].clearToolbar();
    }
}).navButtonAdd("#report_pager",{ caption:"Restore",title:"Restore Default Grid Columns and Filters", buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh',
    onClickButton: function() {
        window.location = '?page=dsp_requestListingNew&clearSession=1';
    }
}).navButtonAdd("#report_pager",{
        caption:    "Export",
        title:      "Export to Excel",
        buttonicon :'ui-icon-document',
        onClickButton: function(e){
            jQuery("#contract_grid").jqGrid('excelExport',{url:'includes/act_requestListingExport.cfm'});
        }
}).navButtonAdd("#report_pager",{
    caption: "Columns",
    buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
    title: "Select and Reorder Columns",
    jqModal: true,
    onClickButton: function(e){

        $('#contract_grid').jqGrid('columnChooser', {
            dialog_opts: {
                modal: true,
                minWidth: 470,
                show: 'blind',
                hide: 'explode'
            }
        }); 
    }

}).navButtonAdd("#report_pager",{
    caption:    "Save",
    title:      "Save Snapshot",
    buttonicon :'ui-icon-disk',
    onClickButton: function(e){
        takeSnapshot(0);
        $('#fltrFrmLink').click();
    }
});
jQuery("#contract_grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
    stringResult : true
    , searchOnEnter : true
    , autoSearch : true
    , beforeClear : function() {
        //set sortnames
        var sn = jQuery("#contract_grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','sortname');
        //set sort orders
        var so = jQuery("#contract_grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','sortorder');
        so = "desc";
        //set grid params
        jQuery("#contract_grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ sortorder:so, sortname:sn });

    }
});
```

colModel returned by ('#contract_grid').getGridParam('colModel') on unload. searchoptions is missing everything for REQUESTEDDATE.  Part of dataEvents and all of buildSelect are missing for BUSINESSOWNERPERSONID.

```
[{"name":"REQUESTID",
"index":"requestID",
"label":"Request ID",
"search":true,
"stype":"text",
"width":75,
"key":true,
"hidden":false,
"title":true,"lso":"",
"widthOrg":75,"resizable":true,"sortable":true},
{"name":"REQUESTEDDATE",
"index":"requestedDate",
"label":"Request Date",
"sorttype":"date",
"search":true,
"width":50,
"searchoptions:{},
"hidden":false,
"title":true,
"lso":"",
"widthOrg":50,
"resizable":true,
"sortable":true,"stype":"text"},
{"name":"BUSINESSOWNERPERSONID",
"index":"businessOwnerPersonID",
"label":"Business Owner",
"search":true,
"stype":"select",
"width":100,"hidden":false,
"searchoptions":{"dataUrl":"cfc/com_common.cfc?method=getAjxPeople&role=businessOwnerPersonID",
    "dataEvents":[{"type":"change"}]},
"title":true,
"lso":"",
"widthOrg":100,
"resizable":true,
"sortable":true}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON don't support serialization of *functions*. So the functions from `searchoptions.dataInit`, `searchoptions.buildSelect` and all other which you use in `colModel` will be discarded after you use `JSON.stringify`.

It's important to know which version of jqGrid/free jqGrid or Guriddo jqGrid JS you use. Starting with jqGrid 4.7 one can define `template` in `colModel` with `string` value (see [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/631)). In the way you will have the main information in `colModel` which can be serialized using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @user2754423: Do you use `template` now with the string values? You can define your custom templates as strings like I described [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/631). If `colModel` have such `template` property then it extend internally the `colModel` with the corresponding functions. So if you examine the `colModel` at the runtime then it will have of case more properties (inclusive functions), but it's enough to save/restore only string/number properties. The short `colModel` will by extended by jqGrid with the functions defined in the `template`.

Comment: I am using jqGrid 4.8.2. I wasn't aware that JSON.stringify didn't serialize functions so that's a huge help. I have tried outputting ('#contract_grid').getGridParam('colModel') without doing anything to it and it looks like jqGrid also removes the funtions.  I will check out the template option you mentioned.  Thanks!